# Buildfire: How to develop using Device Features. (BarCodeScanner, BackgroundAudio, sharing)?

Tags: buildfire

I was wondering if there was any way to develop while using these features. Am I going to have to keep resubmitting my app over and over to test these device features? Also, I can't tell if the BarCode Scanner even opens, let alone if I were to try to get data from a QR Code.

I would like to start using more of the services you have developed, I just don't know how to work with them in the developer portal.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Am I going to have to keep resubmitting my app over and over to test these device features?

No, you can utilize the BuildFire previewer app to test your code on an actual device. Just download the BuildFire previewer app from the App Store or Google Play Store.

> I can't tell if the BarCode Scanner even opens, let alone if I were to try to get data from a QR Code.

The [BuildFire SDK Wiki](https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/Barcode-Scanning-Service) covers how to use the barcode scanning services. You can test your code using the Plugin Tester, which is part of the BuildFire SDK. If you need to test on an actual device, just use the BuildFire previewer, as mentioned above.

Here's sample code for calling the scanner API. The callback will either have a result or an error, to indicate success or failure.

```
buildfire.services.camera.barcodeScanner.scan(
   {
        preferFrontCamera : true, 
        showFlipCameraButton : true,
        formats : "QR_CODE,PDF_417", // default: all but PDF_417 and RSS_EXPANDED
    },
    function (result, err) {
        buildfire.notifications.alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
    }
);
```